# Prove by induction this inequality

Tags: induction

Prove by induction that for $a>0, (1+a)^n>\frac{n(n-1)a^2}{2}$.
I can prove it by Newton's Binomial but I need to prove it by induction.
Actually , I must add that I've already proved it but by using another induction (which not seems good enough) :
checking for n=1 is o.k. , assume for n that :
$a>0, (1+a)^n>\frac{n(n-1)a^2}{2}$
and need to prove for n+1 that : 
$$a>0, (1+a)^{n+1}>\frac{(n+1)n*a^2}{2}$$
proof :
$(1+a)^{n+1}=(1+a)^n(1+a)=(1+a)^n+(1+a)^n*a>\frac{n(n-1)a^2}{2}+(1+a)^n*a$
using a different induction (easy to prove) : $a>-1, (1+a)^n \geq 1+an$
we can write :
$\frac{n(n-1)a^2}{2}+(1+a)^n*a \geq \frac{n(n-1)a^2}{2} + (1+an)*a=\frac{n(n-1)a^2}{2} + a + n*a^2>$
$\frac{n(n-1)a^2}{2} + n*a^2 =\frac{(n(n-1)+2*n)a^2}{2}=$
$=\frac{(n^2+n)a^2}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)a^2}{2}$ and we've done .
Can anyone help please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Prove $(1+a)^n\ge1+na+\frac12n(n-1)a^2$.

Comment: Thanks Lord , but this is my question - how ? please notice , i've edited my question .

Answer (score 0):

we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+a)^n&=&\sum^n_{k=0}C^k_na^k\\
&\geq& C_n^2a^2=\frac{n(n-1)a^2}{2}\\
\end{eqnarray*}